# Increasing a variable when a string exists in csv file

Tags: python, string, csv

My `.csv` has two columns: `SKU` and `LongDesc`. I want to search the two rows below, specifically in the LongDesc column, for specific strings. If a string is found, a variable will increase. The variable will only increase once for each time a string is found. If the string is not found, the variable will not remain the same.

I started out with this:

```
import csv

answer=0
with open('sku.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        def test(x):
            while 'x' in row:
                answer== answer+1
            return answer
    print test('e')
```

Trying to search for the string "e" within the file. However, the only result I get is `zero`. I'm clearly not coding correctly to have the reader check each row, and it's not searching for the right string.

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv

def main()
    find_text = 'this'
    with open('sku.csv') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        found = sum(1 for sku,descr in reader if descr.find(find_text) > -1)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Or, `found = sum(1 for sku,descr in reader if find_text in descr)` ? And don't forget the correctly indented `return found`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When I run the script, no results are returned. I'm pretty I'm just missing something.                                                    Also, just so I understand more of what you're doing, can you explain the last if statement?